# Как занести данные в db2 с помощью merge?

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

Как можно занести конкретные данные с помощью merge? В документации сказано, что в `using` достаются значения из другой таблицы, данные которой нужно занести в целевую таблицу. Неужели нет возможности выполнить мерж со своими данными, которых нет в других таблицах?

Нашел такие примеры, но при попытки выполнить подобный запрос, субд жалуется, что не находит в схеме таблицу `dual`

```
merge into data
using (
      select 'someid' id,
             'testKey' key,
             'someValue' value
      from   dual
      ) val 
on   (data.id=val.id
     and data.key=val.key)
when matched then update 
     set data.value = val.value 
when not matched then 
    insert (id, key, value) values (val.id, val.key, val.value);
```

Возможно, этот вопрос сводится к другому. Как внутри запроса создать временную таблицу, с которой можно сравнивать данные из таблицы-назначения? Создание временных таблиц не целесообразно, т.к. тогда не будет выигрыша по времени, ради которого этого делается. Запросы выполняются с java-сервера и хочется их отправлять с помощью batch. Т.е. отправить один запрос, а дальше отдавать только параметры.

Comment: dual - название псевдотаблицы из Oracle, под db2 такой запрос не будет работать. Замените dual и список полей на то, что вам нужно.

Comment: То что мне нужно-в смысле на название конечной таблицы? Пробовал поставить ее название, данные в селекте внутри `using` пытался задать и  в виде `"someid' id`, и `14412986 as docid`. По названию столбцов в таблице. db2 возвращает "The same row of the target table was identified more than once for an update, delete, or insert operation of the MERGE statement." Какие-то условия не добавляю?

Comment: нет, не конечной. merge into --куда, using - что(откуда), on - условие проверки, when matched - если найдено, when not matched  - если не найдено. покажите свои запросы

Comment: У меня запрос работает под oracle, под db2 конечно работать не будет - там dual нет. В каком контехте выполняется запрос - oracle или db2?

Answer (score 3):

Возможность выполнить `merge` со своими данными есть - `merge` как в вопросе будет работать на *Oracle* сервере. На *DB2* он конечно работать не будет, т.к. там нет псевдотаблицы `dual`.
Если вы отправляете запрос на *DB2*, то надо в `using` указать исходную таблицу которая ему известна, т.е.:  `select 1 from src_table where rownum=1` должно вернутся без ошибки.

Если в среде Java имеется два подсоединения, на *DB2* и *Oracle*, 
воспользуйтесь `insert` и `update`. Практического применения `merge` в этом случаея не вижу.

Другой вариант - вы создаёте одну из таблиц, или исходную, или целевую, как удалённую через dblink и вставляете её в `merge`. И ещё один надёжный вариант - создаёте исходную `stage` таблицу, заполняете её любым доступным способом - dblink, файлы - и пользуйтесь `merge` для импорта в целевую таблицу.